# How did FBI know that Amanda Young was an accomplice of Jigsaw?

Tags: plot-explanation, saw, saw-4

How did FBI know that [Amanda Young](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanda_Young) was an accomplice of Jigsaw at the point of [Saw 4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_IV)? I mean at this instance the people who knows the reality of Amanda Young are dead or in traps.

So who informed FBI about this? Only  Mark Hoffman know about it but there is no mention that he revealed Amanda's truth and he is the person who is also  accomplice of Jigsaw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are so so many theories regarding the possible answer to your question. This question has been discussed plenty of times in different forums on the internet. So I see no extra room to come up with my own theories. Some of the theories I found after hitting Google are:

[First Theory:](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/Amanda_Young)

> 1) During Saw IV, Amanda's ability to pick up the much heavier Allison Kerry's unconscious body into her trap near the beginning of the previous movie is questioned by the FBI, leading them to suspect that there may be a second Jigsaw apprentice. It is unknown how the FBI knew that Amanda was in fact an accomplice to Jigsaw at the time. It is most likely that Hoffman had previously revealed it to the departments to cover up the fact that he was an apprentice as well.

[Several theory from the viewers](http://sawfilms.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog:TeamHoffmanChick22/How_did_they_know?):

> 2) Kerry told about Amanda after Daniel told her, but she never talked about it with anyone except the FBI (Kerry was liason working for the FBI).
>
> 3) In Saw 2 , after Daniel Matthews' disappearance, when the FBI started to investigate the Tape, they found 6 dead bodies and Daniel Matthews in the Safe, However the eighth person was recognized as Amanda Young, when they could not track her, they came to conclusion that Amanda Young was the accomplice to Jigsaw.
>
> 4) Daniel Matthews told Amanda when Allison Kerry found him. And Allison Kerry only told it to Peter Strahm and Lindsey Perez, That explains why she knew that someone else was responsible for the death of Troy in Saw III.!

It also explains that Allison Kerry, just before she died, was not surprised when she saw Amanda!!!

> 5) They found fingerprints of Amanda on Troy's body or something else of the classroom trap!

[And another theory :)](http://www.officialsawforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=1986&sid=9959246555697ce228e648b815e190f4)

> 6) I kinda think they found out through Daniel because after they found him they must have taken him to the hospital and then interviewed him, so he mentions Amanda and his feeling hit on the back. Then the FBI says, maybe
>   she's an accomplice.
>
> 7) They watch a record from Saw 2. We can't see the end of the record, and I think they saw how Amanda drugged Daniel and took his body from the gas house. Saw 4 (when we know that FBI already knew about Amanda) is far later than Saw 2. All the magazines wrote about Jigsaw, as we've seen. So the police and FBI know about Amanda.

These are all great theories from Saw lovers. I have not stated any theories on my own. It is kind of a collection of theories, but I could not find any official response on it.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saw_IV) states:

> Although how the FBI knew that Amanda Young was an accomplice of Jigsaw, at this point in time this fact remains unexplained.

Comment: Is there any official words for any theory to be true.

Comment: This has been known to be a plot hole since it was released. Also check http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0890870/trivia?tab=gf No officials word I could found. i think if there had been a official word, so much discussion have not occurred.

Answer (score 1):

The F.B.I Knew it was unusual that Jigsaw used Amanda twice in the traps and when Danial was found he told them Amanda knew the way etc and they kept it quiet + Amanda wanted them to know that's why Danial survived + by that time Jigsaw is clever and knew police would know that a dieing man would not beable to do the traps alone. Simples!!! By Djxtra

Comment: +1 for the response but ur answer is just a speculation....anyways i previously got an answer. Which is full of these theories.